# Opening a ModalView from a ModalView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, uisplitviewcontroller, modalviewcontroller

I have a SplitViewController with a list of clients, after selecting a client, I open a modalView containing all the information on top of it with the following code:

```
detailsForm *detView = [[[detailsForm alloc] setDict:[[self.curClientList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] attributes]] autorelease];
[detView setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationPageSheet];
[detView setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal];
[self presentModalViewController:detView animated:YES];
```

Then, there is a button "edit" on that controller that should open 1 more modalview.
The button event has the following code:

```
NSLog(@"Edit button clicked");
editNewClient *editView = [[[editNewClient alloc] edit:YES setEditData:self.resultsDict] autorelease];
[editView setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationPageSheet];
[editView setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal];
[self.splitViewController presentModalViewController:editView animated:YES];
```

And nothing happens. If I change the line

```
[self.splitViewController presentModalViewController:editView animated:YES];
```

to

```
[self presentModalViewController:editView animated:YES];
```

I get an exception:

```
-[detailsForm viewControllers]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x53882d0
```

What's wrong?
Or am I forced to use delegates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

presentModalViewController only works if it is used from a ViewController. It is a UIViewController message. I don't think that your 'self' is a controller in this case. Which is why the selector doesn't recognize it. If I were you I would use the delegate to do this. I hope this helps.

Comment: Well, I fixed it. The code above is "OK". the problem was inside the second view controller that had a broken link to a "parent of a parent" object that appeared not to be a controller, like you said. Now all works fine, thanks.